# Count of Consecutive days absent excluding weekends in vertica

Tags: vertica

I have a table with attendancedata having date, empno timein/timeout columns without weekend dates(Friday and saturday are weekends) in Vertica

Please Note:
               1,  The table  is DateTimeAttendance
               2,  Time-In is NULL for those employees who are absent.

So my condition here is

> TimeIn=Null

I tried the following analytics features of Vertica on data and got the outpout as follows

```
select name, date, CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(date - lag(date)>1) over (partition by name order by date) as ConsecutiveDatesCounter 
from DateTimeAttendance 
where timein is null group by name,date ;
```

sample ouput :

```
name                    date ConsecutiveDatesCounter

Aaron Gadsen      19/3/2014    0

Aaron Gadsen      23/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      24/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      25/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      26/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      27/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      30/3/2014    2

Aaron Gadsen      31/3/2014    2
```

Here 28/3/2014 and 29/3/2014 are weekends, so i want the **ConsecutiveDatesCounter 1 should not changed to 2, it should remain  as 1**

I want to get the output as follows

```
name                    date       ConsecutiveDatesCounter

Aaron Gadsen      19/3/2014    0

Aaron Gadsen      23/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      24/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      25/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      26/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      27/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      30/3/2014    1

Aaron Gadsen      31/3/2014    1
```

**Next query on the above result will be as follows**

```
select name, count(1) num_days, min(date) startdate, max(date) enddate 
from (select name, date, CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(date - lag(date)>1) over (partition by name order by date) as ConsecutiveDatesCounter 
      from DateTimeAttendance where timein is null group by name,date ) as consecutive 
group by name, consecutiveDatesCounter order by startdate;
```

**Final Output should be like this :**

```
name                 num_days   startdate      enddate       

Aaron Gadsen     1               19/3/2014   19/3/2014   

Aaron Gadsen     7               23/3/2014    31/3/2014
```

Please help me to resolve this issue of weekend in this scenario..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you really just need to take into account the Friday to Monday.  I'm assuming based on your data set that you don't have weekend rows at all (and if you do, you'll want to filter them for this to work).  Making the event false for that Monday/Friday scenario (while making sure it is only a 3-day gap). It isn't pretty, maybe someone else has a better way.

```
CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT( (date - lag(date) > 1) AND NOT ( date - lag(date) = 3 AND DAYOFWEEK(date) = 2 AND DAYOFWEEK(lag(date)) = 6 )
```